# Apache - Parent: Received shutdown signal

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

I tried to set CakePHP in localhost. It works great except when the page goes to the one that need to read the database.

It just shows:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@dummy-host.example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Here's the error log:

```
[Thu May 09 12:07:44 2013] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Thu May 09 12:07:44 2013] [notice] Child 844: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Thu May 09 12:07:45 2013] [notice] Child 844: Released the start mutex
[Thu May 09 12:08:00 2013] [notice] Child 844: All worker threads have exited.
[Thu May 09 12:08:00 2013] [notice] Child 844: Child process is exiting
[Thu May 09 12:08:00 2013] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/apache2/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Thu May 09 12:08:01 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win64) PHP/5.3.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 09 12:08:01 2013] [notice] Server built: May 13 2012 19:41:17
[Thu May 09 12:08:01 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2504
Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/apache2/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/apache2/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Thu May 09 12:08:01 2013] [notice] Child 2504: Child process is running
[Thu May 09 12:08:01 2013] [notice] Child 2504: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu May 09 12:08:01 2013] [notice] Child 2504: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu May 09 12:08:01 2013] [notice] Child 2504: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Most answer that I found in Google is asking us to edit `C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` to only have one `127.0.0.1 localhost`. Mine has been like that since the very beginning.

By the way, in the error log, it says `C:/apache2/...`. But in my C folder, that directory doesn't exist.

I use WAMP Server if that matter.

Any solution?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I change my server from WAMP to XAMPP and now it works okay. Not sure what cause it.